# Viewstate verification failed. Reason

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

After the user timed out in the browser, he was redirected to another page for login.  After entering user ID and password, the following error was logged in the event log:

"Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check."

The application is running in a single web server, with no clusters.  Any idea what caused this error?

Comment: You should ask the people responsible for the server.  Seriously, this is not a programming question.  You didn't even specify what kind of server you are talking about, nor what technology or language is being used.

Comment: How is the user redirected(server/client-side)? Do you use custom user controls, update panels, etc?